# Unable to see steps in develop script using Ajax truclient in Load runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, truclient

I have recorded script using Ajaxtru client in Load Runner in firefox browser.
Load runner version 12.53, Firefox 47.
When i try to develop it later no steps are visible in firefox.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More information needed to identify where is the problem.

1. FF 40 is shipped with TruClient 12.53. TruClient 12.53 supports FF up to version 40. Make the FF used is 40 (you may click "Develop Script" button to open FF, press F10, click Help menu, click About Firefox menu item, to see FF version).
2. When FF in TruClient is opened, press Ctrl-Shift-J key, the FF Browser Console window will appear. Paste snapshot or content of this console window, which might provide help information.
3. According to the snapshots you provided, the TruClient script was successfully recorded and replayed. Is this script recorded with FF? If so, are the steps visible in FF when recording the script? Is the replay log from TruClient FF replay?
4. Which windows version do you use? Is UAC disabled? Do you run VuGen as Administrator?

Comment: 1.FF version is 40.0.3  and  ctrl+shift+j not working in truclient FF.                    2.Yes the script recorded with FF only and steps are visble in FF while recording and replay log is from FF only.                                                                   3.After a day of my script creation I restarted my system since then when I try to develop script in FF it is not showing steps and unable to record it from FF browser. bt replay is happening using vugen.                                    4.Using windows version10

Comment: If Ctrl+Shift+J doesn't work, there is no helpful information available. I would suggest to submit a ticket to HPE, asking TruClient team to investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the default.xml file which Truclient generates to describe objects. You may see some unreadable unicode characters in that file. I believe this is a bug in TC. It picks up characters to identify objects that it cannot later read during replay.